# Unable to access SQL reporting services on shared site with Themes enabled

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis, themes, reportingservices-2005

I am having some trouble with my IIS web server & SQL reporting services.

At the current time my site is playing host to both reporting services (/reports & /reportserver) as well as my personal website (domain.com)

Only just recently have I implemented a Theme on my site and as such I have placed a statement in my web.config file directing it to apply a certain theme in the following manner:

```
<pages styleSheetTheme="General">
```

Because of this when I try to access the report pages it fails, telling me it couldn't find the Theme. So, what I did was locate the source files for the /reports & /reportserver directories and placed the App_Theme folder in them hoping that would sort everything out.

What I am getting now is the following error:

**Using themed css files requires a header control on the page. e.g. head runat="server" **

Does anyone know how I can get around this? Do I have to hack the SQL reporting aspx pages? Please note I do NOT want to remove the web.config declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on another forum. You have to set the following for the nested web.config file (the one for reporting services) to...

```
<pages validateRequest="false" styleSheetTheme=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the /reports & /reportserver as sub folders of the main website.

Comment: They are setup as virtual directories. how do i move them? Do i have to setup a 2nd site? and if so whats the best way to do it? using another port?

Comment: You can move them using the SQL Server reporting services config tool.  However you might find it easier just to move your website.  You can either create a new website and put your stuff in there then leave the default website in its default state, alternatively you could create a virtual directory for your website at the same level as the SSRS sites.  Your problem is being caused by the fact that they are children of your main website.